# Scraping an Ordered List using BeautifulSoup4 and Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm relatively new to Python/BS4 and data scraping, so I feel like this is a simple problem, but I'm having trouble finding any resources online.

My goal is to use [this site](https://www.randomlists.com/random-addresses?qty=10) to generate random addresses and scrape them using BS4.

My current code is as follows:

```
site = 'https://www.randomlists.com/random-addresses?qty=10'

res = requests.get(site)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

bigdata = soup.find('ol',{'class':'rand_large'})
print(bigdata)
```

This returns 'None'

I see that the data I want is within an 'ol' which I understand to be an ordered list. I've done some basic scraping in the past and am confused why the above code is unable to find 'rand_large'.

Any suggestions?

Small edit/addition: using

```
bigdata = soup.find('div',{'class':'Rand-stage'})
```

returns:

```
<div class="Rand-stage"> <div class="Rand-stage-loading"> Loading… </div> </div>
```

I don't understand where the extra "stuff" is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

```
In[2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  ...: from selenium import webdriver
  ...: 
  ...: url = 'https://www.randomlists.com/random-addresses'
  ...: 
  ...: chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  ...: chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  ...: driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  ...: 
  ...: driver.get('{}?qty={}'.format(url, 1346))
  ...: html = driver.page_source
  ...: driver.quit()
  ...: 
  ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
  ...: result = []
  ...: for li in soup.find('ol', class_='rand_large').find_all('li'):
  ...:     result.append(list(li.stripped_strings))
  ...: 
In[3]: len(result)
Out[3]: 1346
In[4]: result[:10]
Out[4]: 
[['2 Tanglewood Dr.', 'Ringgold, GA 30736'],
 ['7538 South Windfall Avenue', 'Marysville, OH 43040'],
 ['944 Harvey Street', 'Stevens Point, WI 54481'],
 ['804 Smith St.', 'Des Plaines, IL 60016'],
 ['78 Bohemia Road', 'Williamstown, NJ 08094'],
 ['7509 San Juan Dr.', 'Cranston, RI 02920'],
 ['8003 6th Street', 'Inman, SC 29349'],
 ['118 Roosevelt Dr.', 'Fort Worth, TX 76110'],
 ['242 Young Lane', 'Mcdonough, GA 30252'],
 ['3 Marsh St.', 'Bay Shore, NY 11706']]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Could you explain what the code above "soup = BeautifulSoup..." is doing? What does messing with the chrome options do? What does Selenium add?

Again, thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: @jonh98 BeautifulSoup parses the HTML, headless simply means a browser window won’t visibly open and selenium is needed because the content is being loaded with JavaScript.

Comment: @jonh98 I’m not sure how many of these fake addresses you are trying to acquire but another way would be to just translate the JavaScript code which generates these into Python and then you wouldn’t need any of these third-party tools. It seemed fairly simple when I was looking at it last night.

Comment: I'm looking at getting 10,000 addresses. Ideally I would run webpage 10 times with the quantity set to 1,000. I think I understand what's happening with the JavaScript and needing it to load before it can be scraped. I don't mind using Selenium, but I am curious about translating the JavaScript code. What tools would I need in order to do that? Thanks

Comment: @jonh98 I didn’t mean any tools, just kind of looking at the code and rewriting it in Python.

Comment: Ah I see! How can I access that JavaScript code? Is it available in the source for the page?

Comment: @jonh98 Yes, you can see it (for example) in the Network tab in Chrome (F12) when you reload the page.  https://bpaste.net/show/d121bed72128